# クラスモジュール開発でのエラー処理で不思議な現象に遭遇

Tags: vba, debugging

表記、状況は把握できているのですが、「なぜ」の部分が解明できずモヤモヤ状態です。
何か調査のヒントを頂けたらと思います。

標準モジュールで以下を実行 ⇒ test01, test02とも正常終了で結果も問題なし
※この関数は、配列の次元数を求めるモノでエラートラップ方法だけを変えています。

```
Function test1() As Long
On Error GoTo Finally
    
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim s As String
    Dim tmp As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    s = "A,B,C,D,E"
    myArray = Split(s, ",")
    
    i = 0
    Do While 1
        i = i + 1
        tmp = UBound(myArray, i)
    Loop
    
Finally:
    test1 = i - 1
    Debug.Print test1
    
End Function

Function test2() As Long
On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim s As String
    Dim tmp As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    s = "A,B,C,D,E"
    myArray = Split(s, ",")
    
    i = 0
    Do While Err.Number = 0
        i = i + 1
        tmp = UBound(myArray, i)
    Loop
    
On Error GoTo 0
    test2 = i - 1
    Debug.Print test2
    
End Function
```

ここからが本題です。
このロジックをクラスモジュールに導入しました。
test01, test02とも動作は問題ありません。
◆問題：クラスインスタンスをウォッチリストに入れ＋を開いた時、
test02の場合は、フリーズ（エクセル全体）する。
test01の場合は、以下のように表示できる（正常）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

処理自体は、test01を実装して問題ないのですが、
この違いの理由が知りたいと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ウォッチリストですが、単に値を表示するだけではありません。プロパティの値を表示するためには`Property Get`メソッドを実行する必要があります。その際、本来の実行に影響を与えてはいけないため、`Err`などはリセットされる特殊な実行モードで実行されていると推測されます。

今回の場合`Property Get`メソッドを実行する延長で`test01`または`test02`が実行される状況でしょうか？

```
On Error Resume Next
Do While Err.Number = 0
   ...
Loop
```

というコードにおいて

- `On Error Resume Next`により発生したエラーは無視され実行が継続される
- 特殊な実行モードにより`Err`は`0`にリセットされる

が組み合わされ、無限ループに陥っていることが考えられます。

Comment: Property Get の中で、test01, test02をCallしています。  
これはvbaの仕様ということで理解しました。  
公開ドキュメントがあると嬉しいのですが、ご存じないでしょうか。

Comment: @mirai-kikaku 普段の回答では可能な限り出典を含めていますが、本件については公式ドキュメントから見つけ出すことができませんでした。